# select data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables Accountdetails and Accounts

- Accountdetails consists of columns AD_ID, AD_Name, AD_AccNo
- Accounts consists of Columns A_Name, A_AccNo, A_AccDate

My question is I wanted to select data based on the AD_AccNo and A_AccNo being equal

I tried using this query

```
select AD.AD_ID, a.A_Name, a.A_AccNo, a.A_AccDate 
from Accountdetails as AD, Accounts as a 
where AD.AD_AccNo = a.A_AccNo
```

Can anyone suggest me the place where i am going wrong?

Comment: That should work (though explicit join syntax would be better) What problem are you having?

Comment: What is the expected result? What do you mean by it is going wrong? How so?

Comment: if both the tables had 722 rows when uisng that select statement i am getting 4138 rows of data

Comment: Are you sure **both** tables have 722 rows? If so there must be some duplicate `A_AccNo` values so you are getting some mini cross joins.

Comment: i am 100% sure that both the tables have 722 rows

Comment: Well in that case there must be some duplicate `A_AccNo` values. Try `select COUNT(*), AD_AccNo from Accountdetails  GROUP BY AD_AccNo HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` and `select COUNT(*), A_AccNo from Accounts GROUP BY A_AccNo HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: yes there are duplicate account, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
select AD.AD_ID, a.A_Name, a.A_AccNo, a.A_AccDate 
from Accountdetails AD left join Accounts a 
ON AD.AD_AccNo = a.A_AccNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT AD.AD_ID, a.A_Name, a.A_AccNo, a.A_AccDate from Accountdetails AD
LEFT JOIN Accounts a ON AD.AD_AccNo=a.A_AccNo
WHERE .... [your criteria here]
```

Comment: I tried this one too. if i am having 722 rows in both the tables i am getting a result of 4138 rows of data where i should get only 722 rows of data

Comment: If you get more rows than expected, then this is a good indicator that you should be joining by additional columns.

Comment: i tried joing it on the AccName and AccNo including that in the where clause it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Using a join should work:

```
SELECT
    ad.AD_ID,
    a.A_Name,
    a.A_AccNo,
    a.A_AccDate
FROM
    Accountdetails ad
INNER JOIN
    Accounts a ON a.A_AccNo = ad.AccNo
WHERE
    [insert any conditional criteria here]
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a sample of the data you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some duplicate account number values in the tables.

If you have 3 rows in `Accountdetails` with account number `X` and 4 rows in `Accounts` with that same number the join will add 12 rows to the result set.

To determine this try the following

```
select COUNT(*), AD_AccNo from Accountdetails GROUP BY AD_AccNo HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 

select COUNT(*), A_AccNo from Accounts GROUP BY A_AccNo HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The resolution for this depends on why they are there. Is there an additional column you need to join on?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT R.roleID, R.rolename, P.DisplayName, P.canRead, P.canWrite, P.canDelete
FROM role R
INNER JOIN (SELECT rp.roleId, rp.canDelete, rp.canRead, rp.canWrite, rp.moduleId,
            tm.DisplayName, tm.IsActive, tm.ParentId, tm.url
            FROM rolesPermissions rp
            INNER JOIN tbl_be_Modules tm ON rp.moduleId = tm.Id) P ON R.roleID = P.roleId
```

Comment: According to the comments, the original poster (OP) already had the correct syntax.  They had duplicates in their table(s), which caused the problems.  So this question didn't need another answer -- and the one you provided seems completely unrelated and has no explanation.  And what's more, it is the exact SQL copied from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1230530-338-1.aspx#bm1232355

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ad.AD_ID,
       ad.AD_Name,
       ad.AD_AccNo,
       a.A_Name,
       a.A_AccNo,
       a.A_AccDate 
FROM Accountdetails ad
INNER JOIN Accounts a
ON ad.AD_AccNo = a.A_AccNo
```

Answer (score -2):

That's the exact query, you're not doing a group by or something like that?

Comment: For suppose i have 722 rows of data in each table, according to the above statement i should get only 722 rows of data but i am getting 4138 rows of data